# Set ID property of an Entity for Unit Testing purpose only which has private/init setter

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, xunit

For ease in unit tests, I am trying to create a Helper class which basically allows me to get Entities with default values set.

```
var user = EntityFactory.NewUser(emailAddress: "email@mail.com");
```

With the help of named arguments I can override some values if I want.

The problem is I need to create 2 users with different IDs but the `Id` property as you can see below has an `init` setter and I don't want to make it a public setter as it won't make any sense in my application as IDs are being generated by the Database. Also I don't want to change constructor as well for the same reason.

So how would I approach this problem? Is it OK to make it a public setter? Or do I need to save the entities in the DB first in the Arrange phase (What if the entities had dependencies which also need to be saved first)? Or are there any better approaches to solve these kinds of problems?

I don't want to use any mocking library here as I want to do the testing on real objects.

```
public static class EntityFactory
{
    public static User NewUser(long id = 0, string firstName = "firstname", string lastName = "lastname", 
        string emailAddress = "email@mail.com", DateTime dateOfBirth = default, long stateId = 0)
    {
        if (dateOfBirth == default)
        {
            dateOfBirth = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        }
        
        var user = new User(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, dateOfBirth, stateId);
        user.Id = id; // Init Property, can't set here.

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the constructor of `User` assign each new `User` a different id? Then your 2 users would always have different id's, wouldn't they?

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins no, unless there is explicit code to do so. Which usually make no sense if Id field is DB generated. OP said that there is no such logic.

Comment: Is the ``User`` class under your control? You could have the constructor create an "interim ID" as a unique number from a sequence for example, but which is outside the scope of the ID's from the database (for example make it negative), until such time as it is persisted in the DB, at which time it gets its final, true ID.

Answer (score 0):

After 1 year later, I think this is not a good way of testing. Any kind of test whether unit/integration or any other. Should always test the behavior and not the implementation.

In this case I was targeting the implementation. Since I was developing a web app I should have written tests which would invoke my application using HTTP calls because that is the behavior exposed by me app.